# Does anyone have a creative solution that allows me to hide menu items from a web page embedded in my web page?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain

I fear that the answer will be "Impossible due to browser security policy" but I really need to accomplish the following:

The problem I have is that the content to be embedded in my web page includes some menu items that I need to remove/hide because they trigger operations that I need to prevent.  I cannot find a way to address these DOM nodes to hide them.

I have a web page and need to embed a URL from *another domain* into my web page.  I have tried this with  and also by using Ajax to fetch the URL contents and insert them into the DOM of my web page.  These two methods have different results.

If I use  to embed the page from the "foreign" domain I can see the "foreign" domain's content and I can address the  node but all attempts to access the nodes underneath  return null.  There is no error message (in Firefox) but I suspect that I am getting null because the browser is enforcing the same-domain policy.

On the other hand, if I use Ajax to insert the page content into my web page I don't even see the content and in this case there is a CORS error in the Firefox debugger console.

Since I don't control the "foreign" domain I can't modify it to use the window.postMessage(); technique.

Can anyone suggest a way for me to be able to hide menu items that are in content fetched from a "foreign" domain?  (Gotta be a way, gotta be a way, ...)

Thank you.

Comment: Rather than an external iframe, you might request the other page's data *through some server you can get a response from*, such as your own. Have that server request the information from the other site, and then when the server sends the data back to the client, you can populate your own page with the data, using your own Javascript, and then you can manipulate it to your heart's content. (gets much more complicated if there's non-static content though, like JS interactivity)

Comment: Hello CertainPerformance,

Comment: Hello CertainPerformance,  Thanks for a very creative solution!  That's exactly what I was hoping someone would be able to suggest.  I need to do some work to see if I can get that to solve this problem and will report back once I have got it working! Thanks again.

Comment: Hello CertainPerformance,

I had numerous interruptions but was eventually able to devote significant time to your suggestion.  However, I hit a roadblock that I have posted as a new issue.  The new issue is How do I prevent a 404/java.io.FileNotFoundException on a Java fetch of a redirected URL? and is submitted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53822004/how-do-i-prevent-a-404-java-io-filenotfoundexception-on-a-java-fetch-of-a-redire.  If you have any ideas about the new problem I'd really appreciate your help.  Thanks!