# How do I prevent a 404/java.io.FileNotFoundException on a Java fetch of a redirected URL?

Tags: java, url, redirect, http-status-code-404, tls1.2

I need to fetch the full html of of a page produced by an Amazon Web Service.  My question has to do with why I am unable to obtain this html from the AWS servers.

The AWS service provides an initial URL (URL #1) which is normally processed by a browser.  URL #1 returns a Status of 302 and the URL of a redirected page (URL #2).

This works fine when a browser works with these URLs.  However, when our Java code below runs we get a Status of 404 for URL #2 and a runtime error of:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "URL #2"

Here is the code:

```
URL url = null;
HttpsURLConnection conHTTPS = null;
int nResponseCode = -999;
try {
    // Load url with URL #1.
    url = new URL("URL #1");

    conHTTPS = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();                        // create a Connection object for this URL but we don't actually connect yet
    conHTTPS.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);                                 // without this we get a Status = 404 in getResponseCode() below on this initial URL!
    conHTTPS.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");    // try to make us "look like a browser"
    conHTTPS.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
    conHTTPS.setRequestMethod("GET");
    // Java 7 defaults to TLS 1.0 so must do this before getResponseCode() or will throw with javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    SSLContext ssl = null;
    try {
        ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        ssl.init(null,null,new SecureRandom());
        }
    catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    conHTTPS.setSSLSocketFactory(ssl.getSocketFactory());                       // get this connection setup for TLS 1.2
    conHTTPS.connect();                                                         // actually connect to URL #1 (should be done by getResponseCode() but we do it to be sure)
    nResponseCode = conHTTPS.getResponseCode();                                 // nResponseCode is returned as 302 (a redirect)
    }
catch (final MalformedURLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (final IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }

// Use the response to URL #1 to get the redirection URL #2.
URL urlRedir = null;
HttpsURLConnection conHTTPSRedir = null;
try {
    // The prior conHTTPS.connect(); returned the redir URL in the "Location" header so get it.
    final URL urlBase = conHTTPS.getURL();
    final String sLocation = conHTTPS.getHeaderField("Location");
    urlRedir = new URL(urlBase,sLocation);                                      // use these two parts to build URL #2
    conHTTPSRedir = (HttpsURLConnection)urlRedir.openConnection();
    conHTTPSRedir.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    try {
        sslRedir = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslRedir.init(null,null,new SecureRandom());
        }
    catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    conHTTPSRedir.setSSLSocketFactory(sslRedir.getSocketFactory());
    conHTTPSRedir.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
    conHTTPSRedir.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
    conHTTPSRedir.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conHTTPSRedir.connect();
    nResponseCode = conHTTPSRedir.getResponseCode();                        // nResponseCode is returned as 404!
    final InputStream inputStream = conHTTPSRedir.getInputStream();         // consistent with the 404, this throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
    }
catch (final IOException e1) {
    // Get the html of the error page the AWS server returns.
    final InputStream is = conHTTPSRedir.getErrorStream();
    final String contentEncoding = conHTTPSRedir.getContentEncoding() != null ? conHTTPSRedir.getContentEncoding() : "UTF-8";
    final String sErrorPage = IOUtils.toString(is, contentEncoding); //Apache Commons IO
    }
```

Here is the (only) informative part of what sErrorPage from the catch block above contains:

```
The page you tried was not found.

You may have typed the address incorrectly or you may have used an outdated link.
```

If I use the debugger and step through the code and stop immediately after I obtain urlRedir and manually take its value and paste it into the browser we see the page as we should, so this URL #2 is good and works in the browser.  But if I had let the code continue we get a 404 for that same URL!

Can anyone explain what is wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check for any changes in the url done by the browser? (Adding `www.` or `https:` or something similar? Does the url contain escaped sequences, that get escaped again by the `URL` constructor?

Comment: Is there a reason for calling `conHTTPS.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);` and doing all this work yourself?

Comment: In addition to checking differences in the URLs, you might also check differences in the *headers* - if they're not identical, that could be an issue. (generic "looks like a browser" can help, but sometimes it's not sufficient.) You can also check cookies that are sent, which may be relevant if the browser has visited the domain before.

Comment: (I encountered a very similar problem only a few minutes ago, the problem turned out to be caused by my `("Accept","*/*")` which, when I visited the site in-browser, actually had a value of `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8` - I changed that to imitate the exact browser headers on my visit, and suddenly things started working)

Comment: To Poohl:  Thanks for the response.  No, nothing is changed and there are three escaped chars for + = and /.

Comment: To VGR:  Thanks for the response. If I don't call setInstanceFollowRedirects(false) then my very 1st status is 404.  By breaking the steps apart I'm at least able to determine the URL of the redirect.

Comment: To CertainPeformance:  Thanks for the response. I'm having a  difficult time determining what the Headers and Cookies are.  I'm using the Firefox debugger and some Java APIs to fetch Headers and I *think* I am getting the Headers set to match Firefox & I *think* I am retrieving and resubmitting the four Cookies correctly but I still get the 404.  I need to figure a way to confirm that the Headers and Cookies are correct before I can eliminate them.  I tried setting up Fiddler but it doesn't catch the same traffic that Firefox shows so I'm at a loss at the moment as to how to proceed.

Comment: 01/03/19  I replied:
Thanks to all for the help.  I am now able to fetch the AWS page HTML.  But I hit another roadblock that I have posted as a new issue.  The new issue is How do I set a cookie for an iframe with a different domain? and is submitted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030793/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-for-an-iframe-with-a-different-domain.  If you have any ideas about the new problem I'd really appreciate your help.  Thanks.